# How to change speed of animations globally in WPF application?

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation

I'd like to add the ability to globally change the speed of all animations in my WPF application. For example, some users might dislike animations so they'd perhaps cut the durations to a quarter of the normal. During a demo, you might want to double the durations so they're emphasized.

I figured out how to adjust the DesiredFrameRate property globally, but I can't figure out how to adjust the SpeedRatio property globally (i.e. so that the SpeedRatio applies to all timelines and not just one specific Timeline at a time). The animations themselves might come from all sorts of places (triggers, Visual State Manager, etc.)

Any thoughts?

Comment: Incidentally, another use for this would be to have an application that disabled it's animations when it detected it was running over remote desktop or a software rendering environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use resource in all your animatons:

```
<KeyTime x:Key="AnimationTime">0</KeyTime>
<Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBoxBase.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="{x:Null}">
        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="{StaticResource AnimationTime}" Value="Red"/>
    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

Comment: That sort of works, but only at the expense of having to manually modify every animation in the program and continue to manually maintain those changes constantly. The point of my question was to find a way to have a single control point that affected all animations in the application.